# How to get discount applied on cart line item individually?

Tags: magento

How can I get the discount applied on cart line item individually?

Is this possible to get total unit price after applying discount?

Comment: $item->getDiscountAmount()

Comment: Thanks Vikram. But I also want to calculate the total unit price after discount.

Answer (score 5):

To discount applied on cart line item you can use

```
$item->getDiscountAmount();
```

To calculate the price subtracting the discount amount $item->getDiscountAmount(), use below

```
$price = $item->getPrice() - $item->getDiscountAmount();
```

This will give you the total unit price after discount.